# ¿Por que no funciona mi codigo en python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, cv2

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
# Cargamos el vídeo
camara = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Inicializamos el primer frame a vacío.
# Nos servirá para obtener el fondo
fondo = None
# Recorremos todos los frames
while True:
# Obtenemos el frame
    grabbed, frame = camara.read()
# Si hemos llegado al final del vídeo salimos
if not grabbed:
    break
# Convertimos a escala de grises
gris = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Aplicamos suavizado para eliminar ruido
gris = cv2.GaussianBlur(gris, (21, 21), 0)
# Si todavía no hemos obtenido el fondo, lo obtenemos
# Será el primer frame que obtengamos
if fondo is None:
    fondo = gris
continue
# Calculo de la diferencia entre el fondo y el frame actual
resta = cv2.absdiff(fondo, gris)
# Aplicamos un umbral
umbral = cv2.threshold(resta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
# Dilatamos el umbral para tapar agujeros
umbral = cv2.dilate(umbral, None, iterations=2)
# Copiamos el umbral para detectar los contornos
contornosimg = umbral.copy()
# Buscamos contorno en la imagen
im, contornos, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(contornosimg,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Recorremos todos los contornos encontrados
for c in contornos:
# Eliminamos los contornos más pequeños
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
        continue
# Obtenemos el bounds del contorno, el rectángulo mayor que engloba al contorno
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
# Dibujamos el rectángulo del bounds
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
# Mostramos las imágenes de la cámara, el umbral y la resta
cv2.imshow("Camara", frame)
cv2.imshow("Umbral", umbral)
cv2.imshow("Resta", resta)
cv2.imshow("Contorno", contornosimg)
# Capturamos una tecla para salir
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
# Tiempo de espera para que se vea bien
time.sleep(0.015)
# Si ha pulsado la letra s, salimos
if key == ord("s"):
    break
# Liberamos la cámara y cerramos todas las ventanas
camara.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Al ejecutar me da como resultado:

> ```
> runfile('C:/Users/Franz/Desktop/Sin título 0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Franz/Desktop')
>   File "C:/Users/Franz/Desktop/Sin tÃ­tulo 0.py", line 23
> SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
> ```

Por favor alguien puede ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: No es bueno que pongas tantos comentarios, porque en la mayoría de ellos es explicación redundante y además hace el código más difícil de leer.

Answer (score 2):

Los bloques de código se determinan por la identación. El único delimitador son los dos puntos y el sangrado o identado del propio código, a diferencia de otros lenguajes que usan llaves o palabras reservadas (`begin`, `end`, etc).

El error se produce porque un `break` sirve para romper el ciclo en el que está incluido. En tu caso, uno de los problemas está aquí:

```
while True:
# Obtenemos el frame
    grabbed, frame = camara.read()
# Si hemos llegado al final del vídeo salimos
if not grabbed:
    break
```

El condicional `if` está fuera del `while`, es un bloque distinto porque está al mismo nivel de identado que el `while`. Esto implica que `break` no está dentro de ningún ciclo, de ahí el error.

En este caso debería ser:

```
while True:
    # Obtenemos el frame
    grabbed, frame = camara.read()
    # Si hemos llegado al final del vídeo salimos
    if not grabbed:
        break
```

Ahora el `if` esta dentro del bloque del `while` y el `break` dentro del `if`, y por tanto del `while`. Cuando se cumpla la condicíon `break` romperá el al que pertenece `while`.

Además de los errores de identado hay un condicional que no tiene sentido:

```
# Eliminamos los contornos más pequeños
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
        continue
```

Tal y como está, sin un `else` después, esto no hace nada. Si el contorno es menor de 500 continua con la siguiente línea, si no lo es, también.

Falta casi toda la identación, no se si por error al copiar o porque lo tienes así, en cualquier caso te dejo el código como **creo** que debería quedar:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time


# Cargamos el vídeo
camara = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Inicializamos el primer frame a vacío.
# Nos servirá para obtener el fondo
fondo = None
# Recorremos todos los frames
while True:
# Obtenemos el frame
    grabbed, frame = camara.read()
    # Si hemos llegado al final del vídeo salimos
    if not grabbed:
        break

    # Convertimos a escala de grises
    gris = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Aplicamos suavizado para eliminar ruido
    gris = cv2.GaussianBlur(gris, (21, 21), 0)
    # Si todavía no hemos obtenido el fondo, lo obtenemos
    # Será el primer frame que obtengamos
    if fondo is None:
        fondo = gris
        # Calculo de la diferencia entre el fondo y el frame actual
    resta = cv2.absdiff(fondo, gris)
    # Aplicamos un umbral
    umbral = cv2.threshold(resta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    # Dilatamos el umbral para tapar agujeros
    umbral = cv2.dilate(umbral, None, iterations=2)
    # Copiamos el umbral para detectar los contornos
    contornosimg = umbral.copy()
    # Buscamos contorno en la imagen
    contornos, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(contornosimg,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX‌​‌​_SIMPLE)
    # Para OpenCv3 la linea anterior debe ser:
    # im, contornos, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(contornosimg,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # Recorremos todos los contornos encontrados
    for c in contornos:
    # Eliminamos los contornos más pequeños
        if cv2.contourArea(c) > 500:
            # Obtenemos el bounds del contorno, el rectángulo mayor que engloba al contorno
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            # Dibujamos el rectángulo del bounds
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
           # Mostramos las imágenes de la cámara, el umbral y la resta
    cv2.imshow("Camara", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Umbral", umbral)
    cv2.imshow("Resta", resta)
    cv2.imshow("Contorno", contornosimg)
    # Capturamos una tecla para salir
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # Tiempo de espera para que se vea bien
    time.sleep(0.015)
    # Si ha pulsado la letra s, salimos
    if key == ord("s"):
        break
# Liberamos la cámara y cerramos todas las ventanas
camara.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Si he tratado de solucionar ese error que creo que me dices, pero me sigue mostrando esto:

Comment: File "C:/Users/Franz/Desktop/un ejercicio.py", line 43, in <module>
    im, contornos, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(contornosimg,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

Comment: @Fanzo92 en versiones anteriores de OpenCV `findContours` retorna solo dos valores (no retorna image) por lo que la línea debe ser:  `contornos, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(contornosimg,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX‌​_SIMPLE)`. En mi caso el código funciona sin problemas, testeado en Python 2.7 y OpenCv 3.2.0. Si usas una versión de la rama 2 cambia la línea como te he comentado. Saludos.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta añadiendo la nueva línea y comentando la anterior que es para version 3 de OpenCV. No se si tienes más problemas de compatibilidad ahora mismo, ese código que estabas usando es para OpenCv 3 y pareces usar OpenCv2. Saludos.